# How to pass output parameter in a controller in an WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Here I retrieve the output parameter from a stored procedure in `Entity Framework(EDMX)` (the out parameter is TransactionId) here i want to transfer the value TransactionId to Scdid(in the next post method) how to get the `TransactionId = Scdid in the controller`

my API code is

```
 public class StockcountheaderController : ApiController
{
    private adminv2Entities enqentities = new adminv2Entities();
    [HttpPost]
    private  void Stock([FromBody] List<spGetNewStockCountHeader_Result> jsonvalues)

    {
        foreach (spGetNewStockCountHeader_Result Datastock in jsonvalues)
        {
            ObjectParameter TransactionId = new 
ObjectParameter("TransactionId", typeof(Int32));
            spGetNewStockCountHeader_Result Stockobject = new 
 spGetNewStockCountHeader_Result();
            Stockobject.UserID = Datastock.UserID;
            Stockobject.created = Datastock.created;
            Stockobject.CompanyID = Datastock.CompanyID;
            Stockobject.modified = Datastock.modified;
            Stockobject.modifieduserid = Datastock.modifieduserid;
            Stockobject.confirm = Datastock.confirm;
            Stockobject.ShopId = Datastock.ShopId;
            enqentities.spGetNewStockCountHeader(Datastock.UserID, 
 Datastock.created, 
                Datastock.CompanyID, Datastock.modified, 
 Datastock.modifieduserid, Datastock.confirm,
                Datastock.ShopId, TransactionId);
        }

    }


    }
```

Comment: @RahulSharma yes you are right

Comment: @RahulSharma i want the TransactionId  to Scdid

Comment: @RahulSharma actually my API is running when cheking in postman i post values DB and to and work fine  but same time it it could not pass the output paramert to the api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198296/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-rider).

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a detailed discussion on the problem, the OUTPUT parameter was not being returned correctly from the stored procedure. The final solution to the above question required changes to the code:

```
[HttpPost]
private  IActionResult Stock([FromBody] List<spGetNewStockCountHeader_Result> jsonvalues)    
{
  ObjectParameter TransactionId = new ObjectParameter("TransactionId", typeof(Int32));
  foreach (spGetNewStockCountHeader_Result Datastock in jsonvalues)
  {

    spGetNewStockCountHeader_Result Stockobject = new spGetNewStockCountHeader_Result();
    Stockobject.UserID = Datastock.UserID;
    Stockobject.created = Datastock.created;
    Stockobject.CompanyID = Datastock.CompanyID;
    Stockobject.modified = Datastock.modified;
    Stockobject.modifieduserid = Datastock.modifieduserid;
    Stockobject.confirm = Datastock.confirm;
    Stockobject.ShopId = Datastock.ShopId;
    enqentities.spGetNewStockCountHeader(Datastock.UserID, Datastock.created, Datastock.CompanyID, Datastock.modified, Datastock.modifieduserid, Datastock.confirm,Datastock.ShopId, TransactionId);
  }
return Ok(new { data = TransactionId.Value});    
}
```

Once you get the `TransactionId` value in your Angular application, you can use that value to send it to the next method either as a parameter in the query string or in the POST body.